# Select all duplicates except first one in group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, token, cash
FROM users as tu 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE users.token = tu.token) > 1 
ORDER BY token, cash DESC;
```

Right now it returns ALL the duplicate rows based on `token` and ALL the rows are ordered by `cash` value by descending, so the duplicate `token` with highest `cash` is first.

But what I want to achieve is to return all the duplicate rows, EXCEPT duplicate token with the highest cash (basically except the first row from a group).

Note that I cannot use EXCEPT and OFFSET because of MySQL version.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the `cash`, not the `count()`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u 
WHERE u.cash < (SELECT MAX(u2.cash)
                FROM users u2
                WHERE u2.token = u.token
               )
ORDER BY u.token, u.cash DESC;
```

If a token has only one row (or if all `cash` is the same on multiple rows), then the token is not returned at all.

If you only want to keep one row, then you can use the `id`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u 
WHERE u.id < (SELECTu2.id
              FROM users u2
              WHERE u2.token = u.token
              ORDER BY u2.cash DESC, u2.id DESC
             )
ORDER BY u.token, u.cash DESC;
```

Comment: Amazing! That might be exactly what i wanted, thank you!

Comment: @ВикторК.,  I would actually use the MIN ID to Keep.  That would be unique.  What if you have two entries with $2 cash value

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users AS x
    -- row with same token exists
    -- that has higher cash value
    -- or same cash value and lower id value
    WHERE x.token = t.token
    AND (x.cash > t.cash OR (x.cash = t.cash AND x.id < t.id))
)
```